# IF statement based on dates

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an Excel sheet that shows a `Target date` in one column and the next column has the `Actual date`.  I have added statements to turn the `Target date` to RED, GREEN or YELLOW.

How do I turn the `Target date` column back to white after a date is added to the `Actual date` column?

Comment: Hi Holly, if you go into more depth with how you have set the sheet up, showing any vba and/or formulas used, we can help you better

Comment: I think I can simplify....I need to change A1 to white if there is any data in B1 or if B1 is not blank.  I am not sure what this formula would be.  Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If the colours are added by Conditional Formatting it may be best to incorporate the "back to white" requirement into whatever rules you are using but you can use Conditional Formatting to apply a rule such as:

```
 =ISBLANK(B1)
```

with white colour - assuming (a) the Target dates are in ColumnA (b) the Actual Dates in ColumnB and (c) the range you apply this to is either `=$A:$A` or as relevant (or you select the range before setting the rule).

If necessary move this rule to the top and check `Stop If True`.

Comment: I think I can simplify this...I just need the formula that states if there is data in B1 then I would turn the cell for A1 white.  Maybe I can use the above and say ISNOTBLANK?  Not sure...      Thanks so much!  I really appreciate the assistance.